# What does orbital mean in orbital frontal cortex?

Tags: brain, human-anatomy, nomenclature

Orbital frontal cortex is where decisions are made.

What does the word orbital there mean?

I looked around in wikipedia and never find it.

Comment: This belongs to Stack's English section. But surely you know the term orb. As a wild guess, judging from the 'al' in front'al', or later/lateral, I would say the postfix 'al' indicates position-relatedness.

Comment: I think it's more of a fit for here than English.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Orbitofrontal cortex**: the area of the cerebral cortex located at the base of the frontal lobes above the *orbits* (or eye sockets), involved especially in social and emotional behaviour.

Comment: Very good. But that's what orbitofrontal cortex mean. I am asking what orbito means. THe below answer seems to be better.

Comment: I thought that part of the brain is behind the eyes rather than above the eye.

Comment: Did you not ask what it means in the context of orbital frontal cortex? The definition I posted explains it, or does it not? _the area [...] above the orbits (or eye sockets)_.

Answer (score 2):

The boney component of the anatomical orbit**strong text** (in lay terms the eye socket) is the **area** bordered by the zygomatic, frontal, maxilla, sphenoid, palatine, lacrimal and ethmoid bones.

[image: Bones of the human orbit]

The use of the word **orbit** (red) in ***orbito*﻿frontal cortex** refers to the positioning of this part of the frontal cortex (green) being *directly behind the orbit*:

[image: Orbitofrontal cortex location]

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/) for [Orbital](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=orbital&searchmode=none):

> **orbital (adj.):**
>
> 1540s with reference to **eye sockets**;
>
> 1839 with reference to heavenly bodies;
>
> from orbit
>
> (n.) + -al (1).

So my best guess is that it's related to eyes.

Comment: why -1? +1 from me. This seesm to be the one making sense.

Comment: cheers @JimThio, thought I was doing something wrong till now :)